# How to change default dropdown style to a navbar-links and default select event still work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `@Html.DropDownList` extension in my razor view , which **generate** a html dropdown , sort options and **append** a url (query string) to each option.
what i am trying to do is changing it css/html to achieve a **navbar-link** style instead dropdown style. 
i use `@html.dopdownlist` extension for **all** of the dropdowns in my website.
i don't want change the extension code or create another extension.
the picture blow shows what i am trying to do (changing drop-down style to a navbar style same as second row).

[image]

it's my back-end code :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("products-orderby", 
 Model.AvailableSortOptions, new { onchange = "setLocation(this.value);" })
```

client-side code :

```
 <select id="products-orderby" name="products-orderby" class="sortOptionsDropDown">
  <option selected="selected" value="15">New</option>
  <option value="10">Price : High to Low</option>
  <option value="11">Price : Low to High</option>
  <option value="5">Alphabetic</option>
</select>
```

a simple html for my goal is blow but if i want do this , i have to edit @html.dopdownlist extension which i use for all of my dropdowns or i have to create another extension.

```
    <!-- my desired style -->
  <div id="products-orderby" name="products-orderby" class="sortOptionsDropDown">
   <a class="selected" >New</a>
   <a data-value="10">Price : High to Low</a>
   <a data-value="11">Price : Low to High</a>
   <a data-value="5">Alphabetic</a>
</div>
```

- is there any jquery plugin or javascript code to change my dropdown's style  to navigation bar links? (there is a simple plugin called [jquery bar rating](http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/) which change a drop down to a rating bar).
- or is this possible to change dropdown style to my desired style at client side?

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/evumfcb0/2/) with my current dropdown style and what i am trying to achieve.

**Update :** changing code in front-end with java script cause default select option event doesn't get run (dropdown on change event). it's from my controller code which modify my current page url and add selected sort option to it :

```
     if (pagingFilteringModel.AllowProductSorting)
        {
            foreach (var option in activeOptions)
            {
                var currentPageUrl = _webHelper.GetThisPageUrl(true);
                var sortUrl = _webHelper.ModifyQueryString(currentPageUrl, "orderby=" + (option.Key).ToString(), null);

                var sortValue = ((ProductSortingEnum)option.Key).GetLocalizedEnum(_localizationService, _workContext);
                pagingFilteringModel.AvailableSortOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = sortValue,
                    Value = sortUrl,
                    Selected = option.Key == command.OrderBy
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a visual example of what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: @lloyd it's in my picture second row , and in jsfiddle ( it's like a menu bar links)

Comment: also in top of this page you can see sort option style : https://www.flipkart.com/mobile-accessories/memory-cards-readers/memory-cards/pr?sid=tyy,4mr,zzf,7y7&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Memory%20Cards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below on the client side:

```
// Selecting your dropdown
var yourSelect = $('#products-orderby');

// Checking for existing
if (yourSelect != undefined) {

  // Creating div that includes a tags according to your dropdown
  var navBarDiv = $(document.createElement("div"))
    .addClass($(yourSelect).attr("class"))
    .attr("name", $(yourSelect).attr("name"))
    .attr("id", $(yourSelect).attr("id"));

  // Selecting dropdown options
  var options = yourSelect.find('option');

  // Creating a tags according to options
  $.each(options, function() {
    var link = $(document.createElement('a'))
      .attr("data-value", $(this).val())
      .text($(this).text());

    // Appending a tags to parent div
    navBarDiv.append(link);
  });

  $('#products-orderby').after(navBarDiv);
}
```

**[Online demo (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/g0Ln4w75/8/)**

**Edit**

For default selecting, you can add code below:

```
// default select
if($(this).prop("selected"))
   link.addClass("selected");
```

**[Online demo (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/52zktdqv/)**

Comment: unfortunately , when i tried it doenst work , default option select event won't work.

Comment: @Mohammad Why it didn't work? As you can see in fiddle, it works correctly. Another point, It's a sample code and you should change it according your demand. Finally I edited my  answer for default selecting, please see it again.

Comment: you still here? may i ask a question?

Comment: @mohammad yes sure.